# Computing accumulation points of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ programatically

Tags: analysis

I am dealing with a problem where the optimal solution of the problem is any accumulation point of the sequence the algorithm generates. Can someone point me to algorithms that are used to determine accumulation points of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: How is the sequence given to you? I'm asking because looking at only finitely many terms can't tell you anything about the accumulation points.

Comment: @MatthewTowers: As you rightly raised the issue, I would only have a finite number of points. For the finite case, what sort of practical (heuristic) criterion do people typically implement as an approximation to an accumulation point. Many papers in optimization claim results where they show that the accumulation point of the sequence their algorithm generates lies in the optimal set, while not guaranteeing convergence of the sequence to a limit point.